# width-transition not working on ::after in FF

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

I have this menu that I want to try some new animation with on the hover state. The problem is that the width transition doesn't seem to work in Firefox, but in Chrome, Safari and IE. I've tried with both Bourbon mixin and without, no help. Is Firefox not capable of having CSS transitions on pseudo elements or what could cause the problem?

### Codepen

http://codepen.io/stroperik/pen/ByJjmR

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Hem</span></li>
  <li><span>Tjänster</span></li>
</ul>
```

### SCSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  @include transition(width 0.2s ease);
}

span:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to be your pen is working?

Comment: @Benjamin It works everywhere but Forefox.

Comment: Thats ma bad i didn't check with firefox. So I guess you got your solution all the best for building your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Firefox quirk (?), but apparently it needs pseudo-element `:after` to be positioned in this case:

```
span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  @include transition(width 0.2s ease);
}
```

I will also add that setting a "border" like this would ideally anyway require positioning of `:after` relatively to its parent `span` because it allows setting necessary offset easy.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yypeEx

Comment: Thanks for the really quick and useful response! I'll see if I have the time later today to read more about this and report to the Moz team.